# Display connector keeps detaching from laptop motherboard

Tags: laptop, laptop-display, connector

How can I keep the display connector from detaching from my laptop motherboard?  It periodically comes loose, meaning I have to open it up and try attaching it again.  I can't seem to get it to "click" into place.  I attach it as firmly as I can, put the back back on, and hope for the best.  Sometimes it works, but eventually the screen goes black again and I have to open it up again and try reattaching the connector.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something?  How is it supposed to work?  Is there something I can use (tape?) to help it stay that won't short the board?  (Please see photos).

Thank you

Comment: While it is hard to judge from the provided images, it seems that [one of the latches](https://imgur.com/a/VL9B501) which "click" the connector in place is a bit bent outwards. You could try to **very carefully* adjust it. If this one latch is not the cause, identify which latch it is and adjust that one. Depending on what is above the connector, you could put in some non-conducting material which fills the gap between connector and housing to prevent if from any upward movement.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the latch.  What would be a suitable non-conducting material?  Would a pencil eraser work?